# I have no errors and the ads wont show (Force Close)

Tags: java, xml, admob, ads

I created a blank app with just an ad and it force closes when it loads. Heres what i did:

added the google-play-services library to the project
inserted the meta-data tag
inserted the permissions tag
inserted the activity tag
inserted the xmlns line and com.google tag in the fragment xml
imported com.google... into the main java
added the adview code into the main java
saved it.

There are zero errors and the graphical display shows a box that says "ads by google" but doesnt show ads. When i try to run it in an emulator, the app force closes. Did i miss something? Thanks guys!

```
package com.example.abc;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
        .build();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }
     @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It says there is a nullpointexception in the main java. I didnt change anything in the java other than adding in the small code and the import part from the guide. It says it is line 27, which is the adrequest line? What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post some code? And you have added the emulator ID to the add test device line in your java code right?

Comment: I have the line in that says add emulator id but i just left it like that because everything i read said that if it was there, it should work. I didnt find anything in logcat that had a specific number to put in there? Here is the first part of the main java code: 
'code' package com.example.abc;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);'code'

Comment: 'code' AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
  adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
  .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
  .build();
      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
             .commit();
  }
 } '/code' 

Im not sure how to make this look like normal code in a comment but there it is.

Comment: here is a link to another forum where i posted the same question but with the code. 
http://androidforums.com/application-development/848598-nullpointerexception-error-problem.html#post6572800

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks the link works and I have looked at the code.
I have edited your question to include the code.
Could you try it this way please:
And instead of simply importing `import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;`
Try using:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   
 adView = new AdView(this); //I couldn't see this line in your code. It goes under the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And let me know what happens. Also how do you have the ads setup in your XML?

Comment: i put that in and the "adView" in the "adView = new AdView" line is underlined red as an error. It suggests to create a local variable but that then makes another part red so that doesnt work. i updated that link again to include the code for the xml and manifest. Here is the link again: http://androidforums.com/application-development/848598-nullpointerexception-error-problem.html#post6573785

Comment: Yes above the onCreate method you should put: private Adview adview; can you paste your xml code into a comment as the link is not working the page keeps refreshing

Comment: its too long... ahhh here it is. [CODE]  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
[/CODE]

Comment: [CODE]     tools:context="com.example.abc.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
         android:id="@+id/adView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/buttonhelp"
         ads:adSize="BANNER"
         ads:adUnitId="my number goes here" />
    
</RelativeLayout> [/CODE]

here is the link again to the post. hope it works http://androidforums.com/application-development/848598-nullpointerexception-error-problem.html#post6573785

Comment: i added the line you said above the onCreate method and it gave an error so i changed it to "private AdView adView;" and it not just has a warning that "adView" is not used. i feel like the guide should be updated or something because its totally wrong.

Comment: i figured it out, the adview section had to be moved to its own section later in the code.